# Stopping fluid inflow problem

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

I'm new to Blender, here is my problem:

I've created 2 downward facing faucet inflows (Inflow Velocity X=0 Y=0 Z=-8) into a Tank that is half the height of the Domain.

I want the Inflow to stop as the water level reaches the top of the tank, leaving a few seconds for water to stop sloshing around.

I've tried it a few ways:

- Animating the Inflow object out of the Domain,
- Animating the Fluid's Enabled Property and
- Animating the Inflow Velocity.

The problem is, once I insert a Keyframe on any inflow object, the flow of water out of that Inflow Object is reduced to a trickle.

Since there are 2 Inflow objects, I've tried keyframes on one, the other and both: inserting any keyframes on any of the Inflow Objects severely reduces its flow of water. (Baked at 65 and 200)

Please help in any way 
Thanks

[image]

[image]

I played with the file for several days and posted 2 of them up to explain the situation. Both files are the same with the exception of one having keyframes to stop waterflow when the level reaches the top of the "Tank" (hidden in the view). I worked on objects and settings to stop the water flow when level reaches the top of the hidden Tank. If you open both files and bake them, you can see the difference between the flow of liquid when keyframes were added. Hope you can help.

Comment: maybe some good reference image from your setup would help people understand better....

Comment: Thanks m.ardito for responding. I played with the file for several days and posted 2 of them up to explain the situation. Both files are the same with the exception of one having keyframes to stop waterflow when the level reaches the top of the "Tank" (hidden in the view). I worked on objects and settings to stop the water flow when level reaches the top of the hidden Tank. If you open both files and bake them, you can see the difference between the flow of liquid when keyframes were added.  Hope you can help. Thanks Sam

Comment: I have it working, I started over and it works fine now.